# VueJS + TinyMCE: TinyMCE is only displayed once

Tags: javascript, tinymce, vue.js

Please try the code snippet.

I have many components in Vue Router, every component has its own TinyMCE editor to edit content. However, TinyMCE is only displayed for the first loaded router. There is an error in the console: `Permission denied to access property "document"` which only occurs when I use TinyMCE and Vue together, I don't know if it is the reason of my problem.

I appriciate if anyone has a solution!

I have another version of this problem at jsfillde: http://jsfiddle.net/tranduyhung/NF2jz/5105/ . I don't get the error `Permission denied to access property "document"` at jsfiddle.

```js
var Foo = Vue.extend({
    template: '#foo',
   ready: function() {
      // This doesn't help
      //tinyMCE.remove()

      tinyMCE.init({selector: "#tinymcefoo"})

      // This is not working
      //tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, '#tinymcefoo');
      //tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, '#tinymcefoo');
    }
})

var Bar = Vue.extend({
    template: '#bar',
   ready: function() {
      // This doesn't help
      //tinyMCE.remove()

      tinyMCE.init({selector: "#tinymcebar"})

      // This is not working
      //tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, '#tinymcefoo');
      //tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, '#tinymcefoo');
    }
})

var App = Vue.extend({})
var router = new VueRouter()

router.map({
    '/foo': {
        component: Foo
    },
    '/bar': {
        component: Bar
    }
})

router.redirect({
  '*': '/foo'
})

router.start(App, '#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-router/0.7.7/vue-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <p>Menu: <a v-link="{ path: '/foo' }">Working</a> | <a v-link="{ path: '/bar' }">Not working</a></p>
  <hr>
  <router-view></router-view>
  
<script type="text/x-template" id="foo">
  <p>Working</p>
  <textarea id="tinymcefoo"></textarea>
</script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="bar">
  <p>Not working</p>
  <textarea id="tinymcebar"></textarea>
</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving your textareas the same class and choose that class as selector:

```
<textarea id="tinymcefoo" class="my_editor"></textarea>
<textarea id="tinymcebar" class="my_editor"></textarea>
```

On ready use

```
tinyMCE.init({selector: ".my_editor"});
```

Answer (score 1):

Intialize tinyMCE just once, you can make it at the start of your application

```
tinceMCE.init({
  mode: 'none'
});
```

Use the *ready* and *beforeDestroy* events of Vue to reload the editor at every initialization

```
var Foo = Vue.extend({
  // ...
  ready: function() {
    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true, 'tinymcebar'); // id without '#'
  },
  beforeDestroy: function() {
    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', true, 'tinymcebar');
  }
}
```

link to [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NF2jz/5246/)

Comment: This works, but how can I add a configuration for TinyMCE this way?  (e.g. adding or removing tinymce plugins)

Comment: @Robert I used this time ago, could you find a way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes I found a solution like this:

```
// load tinymce placeholder plugin from from local static file
tinymce.PluginManager.load('placeholder', '/static/js/tinymce/plugins/tinymce-placeholder.plugin.js');
```

Here is the full source of my TinyMceComponent:
https://github.com/Doogiemuc/liquido-vue-frontend/blob/master/src/components/TinyMceComponent.vue